# Load data in MVC on Button Press

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, model-view-controller

On my main screen `TextBox` and a `Button`.
I need that when the user type a number, for example: 111111, and press the `button` this shows the data associated with that number.
To be clear, the client must enter their title (111111) in the `TextBox` and press the `button`; pressing it should display the data.

This is the `textbox` and the `button`:

```
<form id="form">
        <div>
            @using (Html.BeginForm())
            {
                <p>
                    Título: @Html.TextBox("buscar")
                    <input type="submit" value="Filtrar" /><br />
                    <input type="button" value="Imprimir" onclick="window.print()" />
                </p>
            }
        </div>
        <div>
            <table border="1">
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row" abbr="Suscriptor">Suscriptor: </th>
                    <td>

                        <b>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Apellido) @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nombre)</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>Título: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Titulo)</td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Ver detalles en PDF", "PrintPartialViewToPdf", new { id = item.Titulo })
                    </td>
                </tr>
                }
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>
```

This is the code with the query to display the data: **CODE UPDATED**

```
public List<Cuotas> cargarDatos(double? tit)
        {
            List<Cuotas> salida = new List<Cuotas>();
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("string"))
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand comand = new SqlCommand("SELECT titulo, apellido +', '+nombre,cuotas FROM datosSuscripto WHERE titulo = @tit", conn);
                var param = comand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@tit", SqlDbType.Float));
                param.Value = tit;
                using (SqlDataReader dr = comand.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        double titulo = Convert.ToDouble(dr.GetDouble(0));
                        string nombre = dr.GetString(1);
                        double cuota = Convert.ToDouble(dr.GetDouble(2));
                        Cuotas p = new Cuotas(titulo, nombre, cuota);
                        salida.Add(p);
                    }
                }
                conn.Close();
            }
            return salida;
}
```

This is the controller code:

```
public ActionResult Index(double? consulta)
        {
            ConexionSQL cn = new ConexionSQL();
            return View(cn.cargarDatos(consulta));
        }
```

When compiling I get the following error:

```
Incorrect syntax near '='//SOLVED
```

**UPDATE NEW ERROR:**

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'The parameterized query '(@tit float)SELECT titulo, apellido +', '+nombre,cuotas FROM dat' expects the parameter '@tit', which was not supplied.'
```

Any suggestion? Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL queries should always appear as single literal strings in your source code.  You should (almost) never concatenate values into the query itself, because it's very hard to do so in a way that is safe from SQL Injection attacks.

So, something like this, perhaps:

```
    public List<Cuotas> cargarDatos(double? tit)
    {
        List<Cuotas> salida = new List<Cuotas>();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("string"))
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand comand = new SqlCommand("SELECT titulo, apellido,nombre, cuotas FROM datosSuscripto WHERE titulo = @tit", conn);
            var param = comand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@tit", SqlDbType.Float));
            param.Value = tit;
            using (SqlDataReader dr = comand.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    double titulo = dr.GetDouble(0);
                    //string apellido = dr.GetString(1);
                    string nombre = dr.GetString(2);
                    double cuota = dr.GetDouble(3);
                    Cuotas p = new Cuotas(titulo, nombre, cuota);
                    salida.Add(p);
                }
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
        return salida;
    }
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. Now, when i compile it shows me this error: `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'The parameterized query '(@tit float)SELECT titulo, apellido +', '+nombre,cuotas FROM dat' expects the parameter '@tit', which was not supplied.'`

Comment: Put a breakpoint for your method then check line to line while debugging and see your action method got hit, if not check your view code. It seems you are not passing tit as parameter.

Comment: Yes, but the idea is that the parameter is defined by the user. So the index should start with the text box and the button. Then the user enters the number and pressing the button displays the data. But I am not being able to compile. Since when trying to compile sale the mentioned error @AbhishekDuppati

Comment: Have you specified the type of command like  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I came across this type of error for below reasons:

If the type of command was not specified even when all parameter values are correct:

```
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

If some parameters had a value of null then SqlCommand objects ignore any SqlParameter object in their Parameters collection with a value of null.
Giving a default value to each parameter in Stored Procedures Solves this problem:

```
@Parameter int to @Parameter int = NULL
```

In some cases assigning DBNull.Value instead of Null where the value meant to be SQL NULL can solve the problem.

In cases where you forgot to give a default value to the output parameter on the stored procedure, you'll face this error.

```
@example int = 0
```